# resharper: break the build if a line of code is longer than n characters

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there a way to make resharper to break the build (give a warning or an error) if a line of code is longer than N characters?

Is there a setting for this or I need to create a custom rule?

Thanks

Comment: It may depend on what you mean by "line of code". Is it just for C#? What about lines split by carriage returns, such as Linq queries done over multiple lines?

Comment: I need to add a rule so I cannot have lines with more than 200 characters so I won't have these code smells in sonar. If a have a linq query on lultiple lines and each line has less than 200 characters, it's fine

Comment: You may be better off using something like StyleCop (and there is a StyleCop extension for R#)